# Which system for make command?

Tags: ubuntu, make, john-the-ripper

I am attempting to use the make command to build a project. However I do not know which system to select. How can I tell?

Running Ubuntu 15.04 on a Dell Latitude D630 with an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7500 @ 2.20GHz x2

The processor was released Q3'06 so I know it won't fall under any of the post 2011 options.

EDIT: 
Just realized these arguments are specific to this program. Below are the available arguments:

```
linux-x86-64-avx         Linux, x86-64 with AVX (2011+ Intel CPUs)
linux-x86-64-xop         Linux, x86-64 with AVX and XOP (2011+ AMD CPUs)
linux-x86-64             Linux, x86-64 with SSE2 (most common)
linux-x86-avx            Linux, x86 32-bit with AVX (2011+ Intel CPUs)
linux-x86-xop            Linux, x86 32-bit with AVX and XOP (2011+ AMD CPUs)
linux-x86-sse2           Linux, x86 32-bit with SSE2 (most common, if 32-bit)
linux-x86-mmx            Linux, x86 32-bit with MMX (for old computers)
linux-x86-any            Linux, x86 32-bit (for truly ancient computers)
generic                  Any other Unix-like system with gcc
```

EDIT 2: 
**[Per install docs](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/INSTALL.shtml):**
Enter the "src" subdirectory and invoke "make" to obtain a list of operating systems for which specific support exists:

```
cd src
make
```

Note the make target for your system and type:

```
make clean SYSTEM
```

where SYSTEM is the appropriate make target.

Comment: "System" is a bit unclear to me with the context you're giving. System as in processor architecture (x86_64)/OS (linux)? If you have different makefiles for the systems, can you give us the filenames?

Comment: I don't understand. Why is issuing `make` not enough? Where do you have to define the system?

Comment: Does `uname -a` give you any of the above in the output? it should at least tell you 64 bit or 32 bit architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7500](http://ark.intel.com/products/29761/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7500-4M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) is a 64-bit processor. So, if you installed the 64-bit OS then you could try the `make` target `linux-x86-64` or if the 32-bit then try `linux-x86-sse2`.